# Compare strings that have different order

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an if statement that compares strings but I want to compare strings that have the same words but different order and have it returned as true.

string 1 a,b,c

string 2 b,c,a

How can I compare them and have the if statement see it as the same string?

Comment: I'd try to find a a way of getting them in the right order to begin with :) All the answers below are awesome but if you can get them sorted to start with then it's going to be much much more efficient to compare!

Comment: I think it's possible without sorting at all

Comment: @deanWombourne Now I posted an answer without sorting anything

Comment: @Kai - it's possible yes - it's just very inefficient to make the intermediate arrays etc - if they were in order to start with then we could just compare the strings :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate the string using componentsSeperatedByString: using whatever string separates your words (comma, space) and put the result in a NSSet. Do it to both strings and compare the sets for equality.

Modified method using mutableArray instead of Set for taking problems with duplicate strings into consideration (as described in comments):

```
-(BOOL) string: (NSString*) string1 isEqualTo: (NSString*) string2 {
  if (string1.length != string2.length) return NO;
  if ([string1 isEqualToString: string2]) return YES;

  NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [string1 componentsSeperatedByString: @","]];
  NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [string2 componentsSeperatedByString: @","]];

  [array1 sortUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
  [array2 sortUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];

  return [array1 isEqualToArray: array2];
}
```

Comment: ... But a,c,a,b and a,b,c would compare to YES. Don't know, if that was intended

Comment: Kai's right.  @"a" will only get added once to the set.  My answer also has this problem.  I hadn't considered that one. :)

Comment: @Kai - what's this obsession these answers have with turning strings into arrays into sets ;)

Comment: @Mario - I really like the first line's quick optimisation - +1 :)

Comment: @deanWombourne why obsession? Just seems the most reasonable approach, doesn't it? How would you do it?

Comment: @Mario deanWombourne is referring to the NSSet approach which vanished by editing.

Comment: @Kai: It's not clear whether those should compare the same or not. If they shouldn't, just use NSCountedSet instead of vanilla NSSet.

Comment: @Mario - it was the 'set' stage I was perplexed by - why weren't answers just comparing the arrays? However, looks like they've all been edited now!

Comment: @Chuck - why bother converting to 'set' at all, we already have an array we can compare directly?

Comment: @deanWombourne: Because the semantics being described here are set semantics. The question is basically, "How do I convert a string into a set?" And you *don't* already have an array you can compare directly — you have to convert it to another, sorted array to get the correct behavior.

Comment: @chuck - not really, there was no condition on unique objects. And I'm not disagreeing with performing _any_ converting at all, just the extra step of converting the arrays into NSSets - why not just compare the arrays? (And yes, I realise we have to convert the string into an array first. I have no problem with that!)

Comment: @deanWombourne: The OP asked for an unordered comparison. Arrays are inherently ordered. Sets are inherently unordered. Which of these sounds more appropriate for an unordered comparison? That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @Chuck - theoretically, yea, sure. However, to create a set you need an intermediate array, which can just be compared. I'm not going to advocate creating two extra objects just to be 'correct' when the question can be answered with the objects I already have :)

Comment: @Chuck and I personally think sorting and then comparing the array might be faster than generating and comparing sets but I have absolutely no data to back that up ;)

Answer (score 2):

Split each string into an array of words. Sort the arrays. Then compare each word in the arrays.

```
    NSString *string1 = @"This is a test";
    NSString *string2 = @"test a is This";
    NSArray *wordsOne = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSArray *wordsTwo = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    NSMutableArray *wordsOneCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:wordsOne];
    NSMutableArray *wordsTwoCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:wordsTwo];

    [wordsOneCopy removeObjectsInArray:wordsTwo];
    [wordsTwoCopy removeObjectsInArray:wordsOne];

    if (wordsOneCopy.count == 0 && wordsTwoCopy.count == 0) // the strings contained the same words, perhaps different order
```

Comment: Same as with sets: "A B C" will be equal to "A C A B" or even "A B C D" while this would not be true if you change the order of sentences"

Comment: @Kai Thanks. Obvious blunder. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

If your strings will always be in that comma-separated format, try writing a method that returns `BOOL` that breaks the strings apart and then compares the contents.  (Writing this dirty ARC style).

```
-(BOOL)compareWordsInString:(NSString*)stringA withString:(NSString*)stringB
{
    NSArray *arrayA = [stringA componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSArray *arrayB = [stringB componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSSet *setA = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:arrayA];
    NSSet *setB = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:arrayB];

    return [setA isEqualToSet:setB];
}
```

Then you can call this method within your `if`:

```
if([self compareWordsInString:@"a,b,c" withString:@"b,c,a"])
{
    // do work
}
```

**Do NOTE** that this will not work properly if the number of words must match exactly and have exactly one correspondent match in the second string as `NSSet` will evaluate YES when comparing `@"a,a,b,b,c,c,c"` to `@"a,b,c"` because each object will only be added to the set one time.

Comment: That causes memory leaks (in non ARC environment)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is turn the string components (words) into an array, sort the array and compare. This way, you'll only compare the words, not the order.

Here's an example:

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];

NSComparator comparator = ^(NSString *s1, NSString *s2) {
    return [s1 compare:s2];
};

[array1 sortUsingComparator:comparator];
[array2 sortUsingComparator:comparator];

if ([array1 isEqualToArray:array2])
{
    //do work
}
```

The `[array1 isEqualToArray:array2]` call will tell you if the strings are similar.

**Edit**

In response to @deanWombourne's comment, I changed my original code involving `NSSet`s to the above code, so thanks to @deanWombourne for his correct and helpful comment. (and thanks to @Kai for calling me on bad editting. Won't happen again.)

Comment: You method would make `a,a,b` the same as `a,b` which isn't true :) (Though if there is a restriction on duplicate words they you're OK!)

Comment: Bad editing! Now @deanWombourne 's formely right and helpful comment doesn't make any sense and seems to be wrong to readers, who didn't see the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting:

```
-(BOOL)isSameWordsInString:(NSString *)string1 andString:(NSString *)string2
{
  if(string1.length != string2.length)
  {
    return NO;
  }
  if([string1 isEqualToString:string2])
  {
    return YES;
  }
  NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
  NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
  if(array1.count != array2.count)
  {
    return NO;
  }
  for(NSString *word in array1)
  {
    if(![array2 containsObject:word])
    {
      return NO;
    }
    //EDIT on comment by deanWombourne
    [array2 removeObject:word];
    //END EDIT
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: What about 'a,b,c,c' and 'a,b,c,d' - your method will return them as equal :(